# heat equation - differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation, differential

Consider the following heat diffusion problem.

[image]

So, $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} u (x, t)$ is equal to:

The solution is $\frac {L^2}3$

I only arrive to 
$$u(x,t)= \frac {a_0}2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cos(\frac {n\pi  x} L) e^{\frac {-4\pi^2n^2t}{L^2}}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read the [tutorial on MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). How did you arrive at that solution? Can you update the body of your question and show your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reason intuitively, then you could do so as follows: the Neumann BC's tell you that there is no heat loss at the boundaries, so the total amount of heat
$$Q(t) = \int_0^L u(x,t) dx$$
must be conserved. You could probe this directly using integration by parts if you want, but it's clear physically. The initial amount of heat is equal to 
$$ \int_0^L x^2 dx = L^3 / 3.$$
As $t \to \infty$, this heat will distribute itself over a length $L$, which means that the distribution tends to a constant $u(x,t) = L^2 / 3$. (I divided by $L$ to compensate for the length of the rod).

Of course, you can also use the Fourier series. Note that each term in the summation you have is exponentially damped, to as $t \to \infty$, you are only left with the $a_0/2$ part. You can simply calculate the first term in the Fourier cosine expansion of $x^2$ to get the solution $L^2/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Use the Laplace transform considering the boundary values, giving

$$
U(x,s) = \frac{s x^2-4 L \sqrt{s} \text{csch}\left(\frac{L \sqrt{s}}{2}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{s} x}{2}\right)+8}{s^2}
$$

and now

$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}u(x,t)=\lim_{s\to 0}sU(x,s) = \dfrac{L^2}{3}
$$

Comment: sorry but my teacher didn't give that stuff - the laplace transform. How could i solve this exercice without the laplace transform

Comment: It seems to me very strange that you are studying PDEs and you have not learned the Laplace transform.

Comment: is there another way to solve the exercice?

Comment: I haven't completed the problem however I do think that you could arrive at the solution strictly by Fourier series.